# Error: Hibernate could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate

[ReportService Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aKyj.png)

```
 private void generatePaySummary() {
        try {
            Map params = new HashMap();
        params = getOrganizationInfo(params);
        params.put("rptsubtitle", "Payroll Date: "+date_formatter.format(tbpaydate.getDate()));

        int i = cboDept.getSelectedIndex();
        int deptno = 0;
        if (i != -1)  deptno = (Integer)deptnos.get(i);

        ReportService srv = new ReportService();
        List empids = srv.getEmployeesInPayroll(deptno, tbpaydate.getDate());
        if (!empids.isEmpty()) {
            PayslipService.setEmployees(empids);
            PayslipService.setPayDate(tbpaydate.getDate());

            RepGenService repsrv = new RepGenService();
            JRBeanCollectionDataSource jbsrc = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(PaySummaryFactory.getPaySummary());
            repsrv.generateReport(false, "/orgpayroll/reports/jasper/payrollsummary.jasper", true, params, jbsrc);
        }
        else
            SysUtils.messageBox("No employees in payroll on "+date_formatter.format(tbpaydate.getDate())+"!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

> I am trying to execute a function which will open a jasper report template.
>
> The function works if it will only process 1 employee from the database, but if I process more with the same date, it says Hibernate could not initialize proxy - no Session.

Comment: A stack trace of the error would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have one collection with lazy fetchType.

> you can solve it by changing it to EAGER mode

So go to `ReportService` class and turn your employee collection's fetchType to `EAGER`. Or add `(fetch=fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`

Comment: The function have too many models. Which specifically model would I show? Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: I mean Payroll and employee !!

Comment: Payroll and employee !!